# Load nib / xib / view by clicking in the cell of tableview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xamarin.ios

How do I open a nib / xib / view while selecting a row from my tableview... Below is my code

```
public class TableViewDelegate : UITableViewDelegate 
{
    private List list;

    public TableViewDelegate(List<string> list)
    {
        this.list = list;
    }    

    public override void RowSelected (UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("TableViewDelegate.RowSelected: Label={0}",list[indexPath.Row]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the didSelectRowAtIndexPath method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NewViewController *myViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
[self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: Should not have a navigationController, just create a class in it?

Comment: Actually you could just present the view controller modally - probably makes more sense if you're not using UINavigationBar.

Comment: Yes, do not use navbar, how would this fit?

Comment: [self presentModalViewController:myViewController animated:YES];
this will create a modal controller that will display upon touching a tableViewCell

Comment: I can not use presentModalViewController in class I created

Answer (score 0):

Just add new view controller as a subView.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NewViewController *myViewController = [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewViewController" bundle:nil];
    [self.view addSubView:myViewController];
}
```

Comment: I can not load any of the nib so that you guys tried to teach me.